# Long table inserting multiple table headers on same page

Tags: longtable

Sometimes on a longtable I get broken output. It will insert the non-first table header at the top of the page. It's very rare and only seems to happen when there's a very specific amount of space remaining on the previous page.

[image: Reproduction of issue]

Any ideas on what causes this output and a work-around?

And the document. It's a simplest reproduction I could manage to make. It's not just \needspace that causes it though. The same issue pops up on a longtable immediately after another longtable, and very rarely after a paragraph.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,final,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{needspace}
\begin{document}
xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz\\[30pt]
\needspace{10\baselineskip}
\section*{Header}
\begin{longtable}{l l l l l}
\multicolumn{5}{l}{Data (continued)}\\*
\textbf{Addr} & \textbf{Type} & \textbf{Product} & \textbf{Serial} & \textbf{Location} \\*
\hline
\endhead
\multicolumn{5}{l}{Data}\\*
\textbf{Addr} & \textbf{Type} & \textbf{Product} & \textbf{Serial} & \textbf{Location} \\*
\hline
\endfirsthead
25 & Data & Data & Data & Data \\
26 & Data & Data & Data & Data \\
27 & Data & Data & Data & Data \\
28 & Data & Data & Data & Data \\
29 & Data & Data & Data & Data \\
30 & Data & Data & Data & Data \\
31 & Data & Data & Data & Data \\
32 & Data & Data & Data & Data \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

I've tested this in pdflatex, xelatex and lualatex on both debian wheezy texlive and miktex, always gives the same bad output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Longtable is in a bit of a delicate state as it switches output routines at the start so using `\needspace` there is a bu
it brave. However your example can be simplified to

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,final,twoside,landscape]{article}

\setlength\textwidth{591.5302pt}
\setlength\textheight{418.25368pt}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz

xyz\\[30pt]


%%\clearpage
\section*{Header}
\begin{longtable}{l l l l l}
\multicolumn{5}{l}{Data (continued)}\\*
\textbf{Addr} & \textbf{Type} & \textbf{Product} & \textbf{Serial} & \textbf{Location} \\*
\hline
\endhead
\multicolumn{5}{l}{Data}\\*
\textbf{Addr} & \textbf{Type} & \textbf{Product} & \textbf{Serial} & \textbf{Location} \\*
\hline
\endfirsthead
25 & Data & Data & Data & Data \\
26 & Data & Data & Data & Data \\
27 & Data & Data & Data & Data \\
28 & Data & Data & Data & Data \\
29 & Data & Data & Data & Data \\
30 & Data & Data & Data & Data \\
31 & Data & Data & Data & Data \\
32 & Data & Data & Data & Data \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Which shows the same problem, which is unfortunate as it uses no contributed packages so limits the number of people who could be blamed.

Uncommenting the `\clearpage` is the usual workaround.

[Meanwhile: comforting thought from egreg](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=6653140#6653140)

Thanks for the clear test case. I'll look later

Comment: Are there any news on this? I got reports about the exact same problem and therefore hoped, there is some other fix than inserting `\clearpage`.

Comment: @Martin ah there is a longtable 4.14 (first real update this millenium) in the sources for the next latex-dev release, I should check the example here, it fixes several reported things, niotably overflow teh page if a normal float appears on the page longtable starts.

Comment: Thank you for that information.

Comment: I just tested with the dev version 4.14. For the example above I see no difference between 4.13 and 4.14, in fact, I can not reproduce the original problem.
For my own file it gives me `! Dimension too large. \LT@max@sel #1#2->{\ifdim #2=\wd \tw@ #1\else \number \c@LT@chunks \fi }{\th...` errors for all longtables. However, as I am using a custom environment based on longtabu around it, I will have to check what breaks here.

Comment: @Martin sadly tabu (and so longtabu) are broken and abandoned by their author

Comment: Yes I know. Unfortunatly I haven't had the time yet to implement a more robust solution for that specific class file I maintain.

Comment: I just ran into something very similar to this. My example uses LuaTeX and a lot of custom code, so isolating a reproducible example would not be easy, though probably possible with some effort. But it's the first time I've seen this. Is anyone interested in a reproducible example? BTW, I don't understand the first sentence. "Longtable is in a bit of a delicate state as it switches output routines at the start so using \needspace there is a bu it brave."? Perhaps "a bit brave"?

Comment: Addendum: adding `\clearpage` before the initial `begin{longtable}` makes the issue of the duplicate headers go away, as mentioned (for example) in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484798/longtable-endfirsthead-and-endhead-not-working-as-expected#comment1225925_484798. But this doesn't seem like a general solution. Or does this issue always appear for a table that starts on a new page, making `\clearpage` harmless?

Comment: @FaheemMitha why do you expect a general solution?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't expect one, but it would be nice.